# Love button not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, button

I am trying to create a love it button the button is here www.dreamsynk.com.

I have taken code from different places and pasted them together, but there are things that are wrong i just am not sure what as i don't know PHP or ajax and my jquery is knowledge is minimal.

I have a database and a table called "loveit" with a field called "value".

Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="love-it">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#like-it').click(function() {
        jQuery('#like-it').load('wp-content/themes/dreamsynk/value.php');
        });
    });​
    </script>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-counter" id="like-it" data-count="0"><span>❤</span></a>
</div>
```

script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

(function($) {
$('.btn-counter').on('click', function(event, count) {
event.preventDefault();

var $this = $(this),
    count = $this.attr('data-count'),
    active = $this.hasClass('active'),
    multiple = $this.hasClass('multiple-count');

// First method, allows to add custom function
// Use when you want to do an ajax request
if (multiple) {
    $this.attr('data-count', ++count);
    $("#like-it").unbind().bind("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'wp-content/themes/dreamsynk/loveit.php',
        data: 'action=add',
        success: function(result) {
        $("#like-it").html(result);
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
} else {
    $this.attr('data-count', active ? --count : ++count).toggleClass('active');
    $("#like-it").unbind().bind("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'wp-content/themes/dreamsynk/loveit.php',
        data: 'action=add',
        success: function(result) {
        $("#like-it").html(result);
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
} 
})
})(jQuery);
```

loveit.php

```
<?php mysql_connect("host", "database", "pass") or die    ("Error.");
mysql_select_db("database") or die ("error");

$increase = "UPDATE loveit SET value=value+1 WHERE id=1;";
$active_rate = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loveit WHERE id=1;");
$val = 0;

if($rt = mysql_fetch_assoc($active_rate)) {
$val = $rt['value'];
}

if($_POST['action'] == 'add') {
mysql_query($increase);
print $val++;
}

$rat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loveit WHERE id=1;");

if($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($rat)) {
print '<a id="likeit'.($res['value']-1).' '; // id="likeit" 
}   
?>
```

value.php

```
<?php mysql_connect("host", "database", "pass") or die ("Error.");
mysql_select_db("database") or die ("error");

$rat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loveit WHERE id=1;");

if($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($rat)) {
    print ($res['value']-1); 
}

?>
```

And then obviously my stylesheet.

What have I done wrong here?

The button needs to be limited to one click like it is now and if they click it again it unloves me.

Comment: What doesn't work? "there are things wrong" is not a good description of your problem.

Comment: You should definitely be using mysqli or PDO, as the mysql extension is deprecated. Are you getting error messages? And have you tried to use Firebug to see your AJAX requests are actually firing?

Comment: I haven't, i cant seem to ever get firebug to work.

Comment: If you test the button it works only with the jquery part of it where the "1" is added but refresh the browser and it goes back to "0". Click the button twice it gives an "error". Which means the ajax and php files are not working? I cant figure out what i have done wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Love It Button not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552846/love-it-button-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

This may not fully answer all your questions, but will indicate some of the things that are wrong.

I assume you copy-pasted the 'love' script from some other site/tutorial.
When I open your site in firefug and look at the console, I get this:
[image]

I copy and pasted the `<script>` bit from my firefox source view into notepad++ and got this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#like-it').click(function() {
        jQuery('#like-it').load('wp-content/themes/dreamsynk/value.php');
    });
});?         // <---------- that question mark should not be there!
</script>
```

Perhaps when you copy-pasted the script you also copied some hidden/bad symbols along with it.

**UPDATE**
Changing character encoding from UTF-8 to Western 8859-1 gets me this:
[image]

Comment: When you click it the second time it gives me `Error.`, indeed. That seems to indicate that the error is on this line: `<?php mysql_connect("host", "database", "pass") or die    ("Error.");`

(Check to make sure the script can connect to your database(?))

Comment: (I assume `"host", "database", "pass"` is not the actual code but are just placeholders, but check them anyway ;))

Comment: Yes its dummy code. Host i copy pasted my host name, "database" is the database name, should this be the db username instead? and pass obviously my database password.

Comment: i just made changes to script.js:

from:
success: function(result) {
$("#like-it").html(result);

to:
success: function(result) {
$("data-count").html(result);

Have a look now, get no error message but refresh the browser and the value isnt saved

Comment: the database table i created looks like this:

FIELD:value, TYPE:int, LENGTH:i left blank and it shows "11" atm, DEFAULT:none, COLLATION:blank, ATTRIBUTES:blank, NULL:unticked, AUTO_INCREMENT:ticked,

Comment: On page load you'd have to get the value of your counter from the database and then assign that to the 'love' counter.

Comment: where would i do this? And i thought my ajax call in my html was doing this?

Comment: You're right, it should load the value. Try removing the 'illegal' character and see if that helps. Delete the last `});` line completely and type it again manually :)

Comment: (That line should be there, just remove and re-type it back in again;))

Comment: confused i removed }); so i must put it back? Ye it made no difference removing it.

Comment: There was a symbol behind the });, breaking the loading of the value on page load. Best way to remove that is to remove the entire line and type it again manually :)

Comment: Whatever you're doing, it is adding something to the end of that line that is breaking the script: http://i.stack.imgur.com/r06u1.jpg

Comment: Woo! Well that fixed that error, but for some reason it still isn't loading the value :(

Comment: I typed it manually now and its doing something funny now. The button after clicked loses the heart, and on refresh it still reverts back to 0.

Comment: Note that going to the link gives me an empty page - are you sure value.php works correctly?   http://dreamsynk.com/wp-content/themes/dreamsynk/value.php

Comment: (I would expect it to output the current 'love' value)

Comment: That funny behaviour happens because of the `('#like-it').load - it replaced the html in the element with the id `like-it` with whatever it gets back from value.php. Because value.php returns nothing, it stays empty :(

Comment: I am not sure at all if it works. What is your email address. Can i give you access to my site?

Comment: Sorry - that is not what I'm here for, unfortunately. (That, and it's time for bed)

Comment: I changed ('#like-it').load to ('data-count').load and left jQuery('#like-it').click(function() { as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, I just tried the script on your page, but it seems not to work correctly, there is only "count up" and no "count down", and also there is no control IP, so that one visitor can "love" your page several times and this is also bad.

you can see this tutorial. It muy help you to:

http://blog.deepscripts.com/how-to-build-a-like-my-page-script/